# gitlab-runner locally, can you set timeout?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using the `gitlab-runner`locally as described in this post:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/36358790/1832293

But my job fails after 30min due to the default timeout. I know that you can set the timeout in the gitlab interface, but is there a way to set it locally? Cheers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written [here](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ce/issues/18183), I think this feature is still not available and is being considered. Maybe you can add a comment to the issue to see how the status is.

Comment: This was implemented in `gitlab-runner` 12.3. You can now specify `timeout: 120m`, for example, in a job in your `.gitlab-ci.yml`. It is documented here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/README.html#timeout