# gitlab runner configuration for remote and local environment

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I realized that some variables are not the same in the gitlab shared runners and when you use your local configuration.

Simple example of a `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
my-test:
  image: docker:latest
  stage: build
  services:
    - docker:dind
  script:
    - env # this is what gives me different results
```

In order to execute this file I use `gitlab-runner exec docker my-test` as explained in https://stackoverflow.com/a/36358790/2237916.

However, the previous code gives me a different result when I push my commits (run in a shared server) and if I run locally. The result is that each one gives me different values on the existent environmental variables. This affects as follows:

- Commands in the script such as `docker login -u "$CI_REGISTRY_USER" -p "$CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD" $CI_REGISTRY` are not able to run locally, because none of the 3 variables are set in the local environment.
- Kubernetes configuration that is use thanks to variables such as `KUBE_CA_PEM`, `KUBECONFIG` `KUBE_TOKEN`, and others, are not set.

Thus, I'm unable to replicate experiments locally and remotely (either with a shared runner on my own runner). I'm looking for a straight way to test in local as if I'm really using a shared runner, with all the same environmental variables.

As some complementary information, my current workaround is to use as indicated in a [gitlab issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/259#note_2539974), with the command `gitlab-runner exec docker my-test  $(printf " --env %s" "${ENVVARS[@]}")`, where `ENVVARS` is a bash array. However this is as far as a proper solution as one can be.

Note: I understand that you can set some variables with the options `--kubernetes-*` within the command line, this is not desired since you have to set everything every time you run the command. I want to be able to share the same configuration that `gitlab` send to the runner.

Answer (score 2):

The variables you mention are only set during execution of the environment on a runner connected to gitlab.

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html

To provide these variables you have the option to extend your run command:

```
   --env value                                                  Custom environment variables injected to build environment [$RUNNER_ENV]
```

There are also a ton of kubernetes options:

```
   --kubernetes-host value                                      Optional Kubernetes master host URL (auto-discovery attempted if not specified) [$KUBERNETES_HOST]
   --kubernetes-cert-file value                                 Optional Kubernetes master auth certificate [$KUBERNETES_CERT_FILE]
   --kubernetes-key-file value                                  Optional Kubernetes master auth private key [$KUBERNETES_KEY_FILE]
   --kubernetes-ca-file value                                   Optional Kubernetes master auth ca certificate [$KUBERNETES_CA_FILE]
   --kubernetes-bearer_token_overwrite_allowed                  Bool to authorize builds to specify their own bearer token for creation. [$KUBERNETES_BEARER_TOKEN_OVERWRITE_ALLOWED]
   --kubernetes-bearer_token value                              Optional Kubernetes service account token used to start build pods. [$KUBERNETES_BEARER_TOKEN]
   --kubernetes-image value                                     Default docker image to use for builds when none is specified [$KUBERNETES_IMAGE]
   --kubernetes-namespace value                                 Namespace to run Kubernetes jobs in [$KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE]
   --kubernetes-namespace_overwrite_allowed value               Regex to validate 'KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE_OVERWRITE' value [$KUBERNETES_NAMESPACE_OVERWRITE_ALLOWED]
   --kubernetes-privileged                                      Run all containers with the privileged flag enabled [$KUBERNETES_PRIVILEGED]
   --kubernetes-cpu-limit value                                 The CPU allocation given to build containers [$KUBERNETES_CPU_LIMIT]
   --kubernetes-cpu-limit-overwrite-max-allowed value           If set, the max amount the cpu limit can be set to. Used with the KUBERNETES_CPU_LIMIT variable in the build. [$KUBERNETES_CPU_LIMIT_OVERWRITE_MAX_ALLOWED]
   --kubernetes-memory-limit value                              The amount of memory allocated to build containers [$KUBERNETES_MEMORY_LIMIT]
   --kubernetes-memory-limit-overwrite-max-allowed value        If set, the max amount the memory limit can be set to. Used with the KUBERNETES_MEMORY_LIMIT variable in the build. [$KUBERNETES_MEMORY_LIMIT_OVERWRITE_MAX_ALLOWED]
   --kubernetes-service-cpu-limit value                         The CPU allocation given to build service containers [$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_CPU_LIMIT]
   --kubernetes-service-memory-limit value                      The amount of memory allocated to build service containers [$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_MEMORY_LIMIT]
   --kubernetes-helper-cpu-limit value                          The CPU allocation given to build helper containers [$KUBERNETES_HELPER_CPU_LIMIT]
   --kubernetes-helper-memory-limit value                       The amount of memory allocated to build helper containers [$KUBERNETES_HELPER_MEMORY_LIMIT]
   --kubernetes-cpu-request value                               The CPU allocation requested for build containers [$KUBERNETES_CPU_REQUEST]
   --kubernetes-cpu-request-overwrite-max-allowed value         If set, the max amount the cpu request can be set to. Used with the KUBERNETES_CPU_REQUEST variable in the build. [$KUBERNETES_CPU_REQUEST_OVERWRITE_MAX_ALLOWED]
   --kubernetes-memory-request value                            The amount of memory requested from build containers [$KUBERNETES_MEMORY_REQUEST]
   --kubernetes-memory-request-overwrite-max-allowed value      If set, the max amount the memory request can be set to. Used with the KUBERNETES_MEMORY_REQUEST variable in the build. [$KUBERNETES_MEMORY_REQUEST_OVERWRITE_MAX_ALLOWED]
   --kubernetes-service-cpu-request value                       The CPU allocation requested for build service containers [$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_CPU_REQUEST]
   --kubernetes-service-memory-request value                    The amount of memory requested for build service containers [$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_MEMORY_REQUEST]
   --kubernetes-helper-cpu-request value                        The CPU allocation requested for build helper containers [$KUBERNETES_HELPER_CPU_REQUEST]
   --kubernetes-helper-memory-request value                     The amount of memory requested for build helper containers [$KUBERNETES_HELPER_MEMORY_REQUEST]
   --kubernetes-pull-policy value                               Policy for if/when to pull a container image (never, if-not-present, always). The cluster default will be used if not set [$KUBERNETES_PULL_POLICY]
   --kubernetes-node-selector value                             A toml table/json object of key=value. Value is expected to be a string. When set this will create pods on k8s nodes that match all the key=value pairs. (default: "{}") [$KUBERNETES_NODE_SELECTOR]
   --kubernetes-node-tolerations value                          A toml table/json object of key=value:effect. Value and effect are expected to be strings. When set, pods will tolerate the given taints. Only one toleration is supported through environment variable configuration. (default: "{}") [$KUBERNETES_NODE_TOLERATIONS]
   --kubernetes-image-pull-secrets value                        A list of image pull secrets that are used for pulling docker image [$KUBERNETES_IMAGE_PULL_SECRETS]
   --kubernetes-helper-image value                              [ADVANCED] Override the default helper image used to clone repos and upload artifacts [$KUBERNETES_HELPER_IMAGE]
   --kubernetes-terminationGracePeriodSeconds value             Duration after the processes running in the pod are sent a termination signal and the time when the processes are forcibly halted with a kill signal. (default: "0") [$KUBERNETES_TERMINATIONGRACEPERIODSECONDS]
   --kubernetes-poll-interval value                             How frequently, in seconds, the runner will poll the Kubernetes pod it has just created to check its status (default: "0") [$KUBERNETES_POLL_INTERVAL]
   --kubernetes-poll-timeout value                              The total amount of time, in seconds, that needs to pass before the runner will timeout attempting to connect to the pod it has just created (useful for queueing more builds that the cluster can handle at a time) (default: "0") [$KUBERNETES_POLL_TIMEOUT]
   --kubernetes-pod-labels value                                A toml table/json object of key-value. Value is expected to be a string. When set, this will create pods with the given pod labels. Environment variables will be substituted for values here. (default: "{}")
   --kubernetes-service-account value                           Executor pods will use this Service Account to talk to kubernetes API [$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_ACCOUNT]
   --kubernetes-service_account_overwrite_allowed value         Regex to validate 'KUBERNETES_SERVICE_ACCOUNT' value [$KUBERNETES_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_OVERWRITE_ALLOWED]
   --kubernetes-pod-annotations value                           A toml table/json object of key-value. Value is expected to be a string. When set, this will create pods with the given annotations. Can be overwritten in build with KUBERNETES_POD_ANNOTATION_* variables (default: "{}")
   --kubernetes-pod_annotations_overwrite_allowed value         Regex to validate 'KUBERNETES_POD_ANNOTATIONS_*' values [$KUBERNETES_POD_ANNOTATIONS_OVERWRITE_ALLOWED]
   --kubernetes-pod-security-context-fs-group value             A special supplemental group that applies to all containers in a pod [$KUBERNETES_POD_SECURITY_CONTEXT_FS_GROUP]
   --kubernetes-pod-security-context-run-as-group value         The GID to run the entrypoint of the container process [$KUBERNETES_POD_SECURITY_CONTEXT_RUN_AS_GROUP]
   --kubernetes-pod-security-context-run-as-non-root value      Indicates that the container must run as a non-root user [$KUBERNETES_POD_SECURITY_CONTEXT_RUN_AS_NON_ROOT]
   --kubernetes-pod-security-context-run-as-user value          The UID to run the entrypoint of the container process [$KUBERNETES_POD_SECURITY_CONTEXT_RUN_AS_USER]
   --kubernetes-pod-security-context-supplemental-groups value  A list of groups applied to the first process run in each container, in addition to the container's primary GID
   --kubernetes-services value                                  Add service that is started with container
```

Comment: I updated the question. However, what want is to have both environments synced. It should be possible because gitlab generates the variables that are sent to the gitlab-runner.