# Running default before_script in gitlab-runner docker exec

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I have a gitlab ci configuration that I want to run locally. I can see that I can do that using `gitlab-runner docker exec` in this answer: [Use GitLab CI to run tests locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32933174/use-gitlab-ci-to-run-tests-locally). However, my gitlab configuration uses a default before_script, and when I run a job with `gitlab-runner docker exec <job-id>`, the default before_script doesn't get run.

Here is an example configuration that demonstrates the issue

```
image: openjdk:8

default:
  before_script:
    - echo TEST1
    - echo TEST1
    - echo TEST1
    - echo TEST1

test:
  script:
    - echo TEST3
```

I can get default before_script to run in the gitlab pipeline, just not locally. If I run `gitlab-runner exec docker test` with this configuration, only the TEST3 gets printed. How can I get the default before_script to run?

Comment: just a suggestion, what about adding `stages` after `image` define. in it `default,test` stages are defined. If it doesnt work, place `before_script` as a separate stage.

Comment: @SachithMuhandiram sorry I can't understand your comment, can you clarify?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the `default:` yml keyword is not currently supported by the `gitlab-runner exec` command: https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/#limitations-of-gitlab-runner-exec. So there appears to be no way to do what I am trying to do.

There is apparently plans by Gitlab to fix this: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/2797, but no timeline given for when/if this will be delivered.

Answer (score 0):

```
image: openjdk:8

stages:
  - default
  - test

default:
  before_script:
    - echo TEST1
    - echo TEST1
    - echo TEST1
    - echo TEST1

test:
  script:
    - echo TEST3
```

or

```
before_script:
    - echo TEST1
    - echo TEST1
    - echo TEST1
    - echo TEST1

test:
  script:
    - echo TEST3
```

Comment: I think there's some confusion. `default:` is not the name of a job, it's the `default` keyword in gitlab: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/. It means that all jobs should inherit the before_script in it. Also, adding the `stages` section does not help because the only way I know of to run the docker executor locally is to run a specific job, which bypasses the `stages` section. Moving the `before_script` out of `default` works for this case, but would require me to make major changes to my gitlab yml which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in this issue [Local pipeline execution issue](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/2797), the `default` keyword is deprecated, gitlab-runner not support it. Just write gloabl before_script like this:

```yaml
stages:
  - test

before_script:
  - echo TEST1
  - echo TEST1
  - echo TEST1
  - echo TEST1

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo TEST3
```

test with comamnd:

```bash
gitlab-runner exec docker --docker-image openjdk:11.0.16 --docker-pull-policy if-not-present test
```