# edit and execute pipeline *.yml template file from command line

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-api

I am modifying an existing, really long, "spaghetti" GitLab pipeline template file (*.yml).

**My problem is that if I want to test the modification I made in the yml file then**

1. I need to push/commit the pipeline yml file after the modification, sometimes character by character
2. then I need to run the pipeline on a real project
3. then navigate to the pipeline logs section on the GitLab web and check the logs on the web user interface stage by stage

This process is really painful and time-consuming.
Especially because as I know there is no way to see on the GitLab web user interface the FULL log of pipeline execution. I only can see logs stage by stage. This waiting and clicking-clicking slow me so much.

**My question is the following:**

Can I edit and run the pipeline yml file somehow from the command line (form the server where GitLab runs) and see the result (the log) immediately without pushing the file and clicking on the GitLab web interface?

Can I see somehow the complete log of a pipeline execution? Not only the log belongs to a stage.

We use GitLab v13.12.6.

Comment: Sounds like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/a/36358790/2307873