# See Gitlab CI/CD pipeline on my local machine

Tags: terminal, gitlab-ci, git-push, gitlab-pipelines

I am using gitlab on a server for storing and managing our projects.
But each time I push my code, I have to:

=> log on the gitlab's front

=> select my project

=> CI/CD

=> Pipeline

Is there a way to see that terminal running all the .gitlab-ci.yml stuff right after my `git push` command on my local comnputer ?

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36358790/5721620) answers your question?

Comment: @DavideMadrisan indeed it does thanks