# Running gitlab-runner on the command line in a docker container

Tags: docker, gitlab-ci-runner

I setup up gitlab-runner on my machine to run from a docker container as per [these instructions](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/docker.html). Then I try to run it with this command:

```
docker run -v /etc/gitlab-runner:/etc/gitlab-runner --rm -it gitlab/gitlab-runner exec docker test
```

I expect that this will run the 'test' stage of my .gitlab-ci.yml file using the 'docker' executor. Instead it exits with this message:

```
fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git
```

I also tried it with "--env CI_PROJECT_DIR=." but got the same result. Do I need to set some variable so that it will know what Git repo to clone? Or is it easier to just install the 'gitlab-runner' binary on my Linux box and use that for CLI testing?

Answer (score 0):

From the [docs](https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/commands/#gitlab-runner-exec):

> If you want to use the docker executor with the exec command, use that in context of docker-machine shell or boot2docker shell. This is required to properly map your local directory to the directory inside the Docker container.

```
gitlab-runner exec docker ...
```

doesn't seem to work at all in CLI.

Answer (score 0):

docker run --rm -v $PWD:$PWD -v /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock -v /opt/gitlab-runner/config:/etc/gitlab-runner --workdir $PWD gitlab/gitlab-runner exec docker deploy. Option --workdir is the key.

[Use GitLab CI to run tests locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32933174/use-gitlab-ci-to-run-tests-locally#comment116372207_46150692)